# default email format on contact creation

Tags: contacts, email, default-settings

I am sure I found the solution I am looking for for an older release of civicrm. Currently I have installed 4.7.2. and can not find a way to set the default value for new contacts (individual or organisations) to html-email (section-communication) and have some sections (contact_details, communication, demographics, tags and groups) open?

I did not make a record and now I could not find these Instructions again. Can anybody assist or give me a hint where to look. Thank you!

Bret